# Accessing subclass members when using polymorphism and List

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 3 classes: **"ChemDataChemicals**(Super)", "**ChemDataAlcohol**(Sub), "**ChemDataAcidBase**"(Sub) and a common List( type: ChemDataChemicals) which holds all the objects. My superClass holds most of my fields but the subclasses are both containing one extra field each - pH(decimal) and VolPercentage(decimal).

The code below should add the item.Name and item.VolPercentage/item.pH in a ListBox, but I can't get access to my field in my subclass.

```
 foreach (ChemDataChemicals item in tmpChemDataChemicalsList)
        {
            if (item is ChemDataAlcohol)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}: {1}%", item.Name, (ChemDataAlcohol)item.VolPercentage));
            }

            else if (item is ChemDataAcidBase)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}: {1}M", item.Name, item.pH));
            }
        }
```

I've tried some casting, but nothing seems to work. (Windows Forms - C#)
Thanks,

Comment: IMO you should retag "not-polymorphism". LOL. You should add an abstract member in base class like "ToShortDescription()" and override it in derived classes. Get rid of "item is XYZ"...

Comment: Hi Adriano. I'm quite new to programming and have just started on understanding OOP. I thought, that the ability to use the superclass reference when calling obj was polymorphism. In other words that the chemDataAcidBase(sub) obj is an chemDataChemical(super) obj due to inheritance. Have I misunderstood the concept ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
(ChemDataAlcohol)item.VolPercentage
```

to

```
((ChemDataAlcohol)item).VolPercentage
```

---

Also, I suggest you to use `as` keyword:

```
(item as ChemDataAlcohol).VolPercentage
```

Because, with the first method, if the cast fails, an **exception is thrown**. With the `as` method, it results in null, which can be checked for, and **avoid an exception being thrown**.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to access items of just one subclass from the list, if you have a more general problem, and that's to use the OfType<T> extension method on any collection.

```
private class Chemical
{
    public string formula;
}
private class ChemDataAlcohol : Chemical
{
    public string Name;
}
private class ChemDataAcidBase : Chemical
{
    public decimal pH; // at 1.0 M
}

public static void Test()
{
    Chemical[] chemicals = {
        new Chemical { formula = "H2O" },
        new ChemDataAcidBase { formula = "H2SO4", pH = 0 },
        new ChemDataAlcohol { formula = "C2H6O", Name="ethanol" },
        new Chemical { formula = "CO2" },
        new ChemDataAcidBase { formula = "CH3COOH", pH = 2.4M },
                            };

    List<ChemDataAlcohol> alcohols = chemicals.OfType<ChemDataAlcohol>().ToList();
    foreach (ChemDataAlcohol alcohol in alcohols) { string name = alcohol.Name; }

    List<ChemDataAcidBase> acids = chemicals.OfType<ChemDataAcidBase>().ToList();
    foreach (ChemDataAcidBase acid in acids) { decimal pH = acid.pH; }
}
```

Downsides: it isn't appropriate in every circumstance, and would take a certain amount of adapting to fit the need in your question.